# Receiving text and email

Tags: iphone

I need to know if it is possible to develop an application to read and reply to SMS and email. If so, how could this be done (what library/class needs to be used). I've searched all apps there isn't an app that does this. There's only an app that requires you to set your email and constantly checks for new message however SMS I'm not sure if there's an app that does this thereby I'm not sure if it could be done. Thanks,

Regards,

Heba

Answer (score 2):

Without a jailbroken iPhone, no. You can't interact with the other native applications beyond what the APIs provide (i.e. accessing the photos and media library). Like the other e-mail application, you could fake the e-mail situation by requiring them to provide you their servers and credentials. However, you really can't access the SMS history nor respond to them.